# How to bind property using a formatter

Tags: binding, javafx

I have a label and a double property. I'd like to output the value with the postfix "$", i. e. "200.50 $". How can I do this with JavaFX? I thought about using binding like this:

```
@FXML Label label;
DoubleProperty value;
...
Bindings.bindBidirectional( label.textProperty(), valueProperty(), NumberFormat.getInstance());
```

But haven't found a way to append the " $" to the text.

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Isnt there something like Bindings.format("%d $", propertyValue); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to ItachiUchiha and NDY I got on the right track to the answer. I'll have to use a StringConverter like this:

```
  public class MoneyStringConverter extends StringConverter<Number> {

    String postFix = " $";
    NumberFormat formatter = numberFormatInteger; 

    @Override
    public String toString(Number value) {

        return formatter.format( value) + postFix;

    }

    @Override
    public Number fromString(String text) {

      try {

        // we don't have to check for the symbol because the NumberFormat is lenient, ie 123abc would result in the value 123
        return formatter.parse( text);

      } catch( ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException( e);
      }

    }

  }
```

And then I can use it in the binding:

```
Bindings.bindBidirectional( label.textProperty(), valueProperty(), new MoneyStringConverter());
```

Comment: I still think, this method is not very great (for unidirectional binding). I'd prefer `label.textProperty().bind(doubleProperty().asString("%.2f"));` - much shorter and more easy to read.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work.

```
Bindings.format("%.2f $", myDoubleProperty.getValue());
```

Now you can bind it

```
 label.textProperty.bind(Bindings.format("%.2f $", myDoubleProperty.getValue());
```

If you want to use the NumberFormat instance, just format the value of the myDoubleProperty with it.

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
formatter.setSomething();
formatter.format(myDoubleProperty.getValue());
```

Now add it to our Bindings.format.

Edit:

Included inputs of ItachiUchiha.

Comment: Better to use `label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%.2f $",value));`, since it is a `DoubleProperty`

Comment: Thank you, but I need to use a formatter, not a format String.

Comment: not sure what you exactly want to do, but you can just format your property value and use Bindings.format after that to add the $? See my edit.

Comment: When I invoke setValue(123), I'd like to implicitly have the label updated to "123 $". An external formatter doesn't get invoked unless I use it in a change listener. I just found out that there's something like a StringConverter. I think I'll have to use that one. I'll post the code as answer. Thanks for your help guys. It's not the solution, but it brought me there.

Comment: Great :) I kinda misunderstood your idea but its good that you found your own way!

Answer (score 1):

You can just concat it to the value using

```
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat(value).concat("$"));
```

Comment: Thank you, but do you know how to use that with a NumberFormat instance?

Comment: I am not sure if NumberFormat can do that, since, numberformat has predefined prefix/postfix expressions for currency.

Comment: it seems to work with the MoneyStringConverter that I posted. Or do you see a problem in that? The main goal is to have a setValue() method and everything should update implicitly without having to use a ChangeListener or e. g. multiple updateTextField() methods.

Comment: I did not see your answer, nice to see an implementation of StringConverter. Just one thing that bugs me is, since money will always be in decimal format, why not use `DecimalFormat` instead of `NumberFormat`?

Comment: That was just an example formatter. I need it to also show e. g. degrees with 2 decimals, a datetime format of hours with " h" as postfix and the likes. But you are right, if money is involved, DecimalFormat should be used.